# Base64 Conversion

Tags: java, c#

I have a string that is encoded as base64 by using the `Convert.ToBase64String()` in C#. 
I want to decode the same string in Java. How is it possible? I am using:

```
decodedString = Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(data);
```

And it shows this error:

> Exception in thread "Thread-6" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Input byte

Comment: Methods for decoding base64 in Java are well-documented. If you are having trouble getting one or more of those methods to work, and you would like help from the Stack Overflow community, make sure that your question includes a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces your problem. See also [ask], including articles linked at the bottom of that page, for more advice about how to present your question in a clear, answerable way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below

```
byte [] valueDecoded = Base64.decodeBase64(data);
System.out.println("Decoded value is " + new String(valueDecoded));
```

Comment: But it showing compile error ,its undefine function

Comment: May be you have not added Class Base64 reference reference in your project, you can check the docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can decode it by doing the following:

```
// just an example (put your string here)
String encodedStr = "aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ=";

byte [] valueDecoded = java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedStr);
System.out.println("Decoded string: " + new String(valueDecoded));
```

**Output**:

```
Decoded string: hello world
```